# Letter to word assignment

Tags: c#

I'm practicing programming in C sharp and i'm trying to write a program that will ask for a letter value from the user and output a word value eg. the user inputs the letter "a" and gets the word "apple". What would be the best code for this?  Cheers.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We're much more likely to be able to help you if you take a crack at the problem yourself and [describe what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com). Check the Stack Overflow [question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) for more information on asking the right questions. Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: I had no idea practicing could be defined as asking others to do something for you...

Answer (score 3):

Hint: use a [`Dictionary`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary).

```
var dict = new Dictionary<char, string>() {
  {'a', "apple"},
  {'b', "box"},
  // ......
  {'z', "zebra"}
};

dict['a']; // apple
```

Comment: I see what you did there, bravo!